# Merge the array that have the same specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_session] => 174
            [id_participant] => 191
            [participant] => A[mail1@xy.com]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id_session] => 175
            [id_participant] => 177
            [participant] => B[mail2@xy.com]
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id_session] => 175
            [id_participant] => 189
            [participant] => C[mail3@xy.com]
        )

)
```

I wan to get the json or an multiple dim array

```
Array
(
    [174] => Array([191]=>A[mail1@xy.com]),
    [175] => Array
        (            
            [177] => B[mail2@xy.com],
            [189] => C[mail3@xy.com]
        )

)
```

Anyone could help me how do that?

thanks

Comment: when you build your array, or loop through the results do $result[$record['id_session']][]=$record['participant'];

Comment: I build from SQL SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// initialize the array which will contain the result
$resultArray = [];
foreach($sourceArray as $item) {
    // if there is no item in the array with the session is init the item
    if (!array_key_exists($item['id_session'], $resultArray)) {
        $resultArray[$item['id_session']] = [];
    }

    // add the item to the result
    $resultArray[$item['id_session']][$item['id_participant']] = $item['participant'];
}
```

Note that I have used the new array syntax. If you are using PHP < 5.4 you should replace `[]` by `array()`.

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mosJlr)

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($old_array as $inner_array) {
    if(!isset($new_array[$inner_array['id_session']]))
        $new_array[$inner_array['id_session']] = array();
    $new_array[$inner_array['id_session']][] = $inner_array['participant'];
}
```

Comment: PHP uses $ for variables like $inner_array['id_session']

Answer (score 0):

Where $result will be your new structure and $array is your existing one:

```
 $result=array();
 foreach($array as $record)
 {
    $result[$record['id_session']][$record['id_participant']]=$record['participant']; 
 }
```

OR

```
$result=array();
while($record=mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result))
{
    $result[$record['id_session']][$record['id_participant']]=$record['participant']; 
}
```

Comment: `$result[$record['id_session']][]`..will error out if index `id_session` is not found in `$record`..

Comment: updated and $record WILL have it set according to OP specifications